# Do I need curved RF tracks for a chip antenna?

Tags: integrated-circuit, antenna

I'm doing a PCB layout with a chip antenna on my board.

Is it important to make curved RF tracks from the MCU to the chip antenna or is it only important to have curved traces if I have RF connectors?

[image]

Comment: Read the antennas datasheet, it should come with a few design considerations and examples. What do you exactly mean by curved? to ensure electron acceleration?

Comment: There is no available example in the datasheet.  https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/as/2066490001-AS.pdf Curved means smooth curves not 45 or 90 degrees angle on the transmission lines.

Comment: I have read the datasheet and there is no information about it.

Comment: This is not a direct answer but its worth a read https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/336754/nrf52-and-chip-antenna-layout-questions?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet won't address what the transmission line should look like.

It assumes you use a properly matched transmission line.

As long as the impedance is correct along the entire length, it doesn't matter if the traces are straight, rounded, curved or zig-zagged.

You may find it difficult to make a transmission line in a particular shape and still be able to guarantee the proper impedance.  That's not something the antenna manufacturer can influence.

The datasheet shows dimensions (or rather, to scale drawings) for the matching network.  You should probably try your best to stick to those recommendations.

Comment: I followed the recommendations in the datasheet in terms of the dimensions and matching network. Please see above image. However, I'm curious about the PCB size, what would be the effect if I use smaller PCB size 65x28mm. The reference PCB size they use is 130x60mm.

Comment: If you change the size of the ground plane, the it'll most certainly change the radiation pattern.  It'd take expensive simulation software to tell what that would do.  Alternatively, you build your board and have the radiation pattern tested like they did for the demo board.

Comment: In section 7.3 RF PERFORMANCE AS A FUNCTION ON DIFFERENT SIZE GROUND in this document https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/as/2066490001-AS.pdf, They use three kinds of ground plane size for the RF performance. Could you help me understand what does it mean when they said "When customers apply different PCB size ground,
new matching network should be used for return loss and efficiency improvement." New matching network meaning the values of the components used in matching circuit or the matching network type?

Comment: Sounds to me like you would have to change the layout and values of the matching network

Comment: It seems that it is going to be complicated in my situation considering the size of the ground plane I'm designing is much smaller than those mentioned in the datasheet.